# How to query id based on max created date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by, spring-data

For below records stored in mongo I wants to find latest id for each group based on latest created date where status is success.

I am expecting *result* as, what will be the query? I am using *spring data*:

```
group Id    Id

g1          id3
g2          id6
```

*group_status:*

```
Id      status    created date    group id

id1    SUCCESS     2018-10-29       g1
id2    FAILED      2018-12-30       g1
id3    SUCCESS     2018-12-22       g1
id4    SUCCESS     2018-09-16       g1
id5    SUCCESS     2018-09-29       g2
id6    SUCCESS     2018-11-13       g2
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation using Spring Data:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "spr_test");
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        match(where("status").is("SUCCESS")),
        sort(ASC, "groupId").and(DESC, "createdDate"),
        group("groupId").first("id").as("id"),
        project("id").and("_id").as("groupId").andExclude("_id")
);

AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "test", Document.class);
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```